# RcppArmadillo: conflicting declaration of C function 'SEXPREC* sourceCpp_1_hh(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)'

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

My code is the following

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h> 

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
//RNGScope scope; 

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::mat hh(arma::mat Z, int n, int m){
    
    if(Z.size()==0){
        
        Z = arma::randu<mat>(n,m); # if matrix Z is null, then generate random numbers to fill in it
        return Z;
    
    }else{
        
        return Z;
    }
}
```

Error reported:

```
conflicting declaration of C function 'SEXPREC* sourceCpp_1_hh(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)'
```

Do you have any idea about this question?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove unused //RNGScope scope. Additionally more clear is to use arma::mat(x,y, arma::fill::randu). You can not declare #include <Rcpp.h>  so remove it. Rcpp is already in RcppArmadillo.

Comment: @polkas Thank you for your answer! To be honest, I am a RcppArmadillo beginner. I often feel confused with some errors, unfortunately, no much online resources are provided to solve my problems. I will post my questions on StackOverflow in the future. And hope that it can help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's slow down and clean up, following other examples:

1. Never ever include both `Rcpp.h` and `RcppArmadillo.h`. It errors. And `RcppArmadillo.h` pulls in `Rcpp.h` for you, and at the right time. (This matters for the generated code.)
2. No need to mess with `RNGScope` unless you *really* know what your are doing.
3. I recommend against flattening namespaces.
4. For reasons discussed elsewhere at length, you probably want R's RNGs.
5. The code doesn't compile as posted: C++ uses `//` for comments, not `#`.
6. The code doesn't compile as posted: Armadillo uses different matrix creation.
7. The code doesn't run as intended as `size()` is not what you want there. We also do not let a 'zero element' matrix in---maybe a constraint on our end.

That said, once repaired, we now get correct behavior for a slightly changed spec:

Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/63984142/answer.cpp")

R> hh(2, 2)
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.359028 0.775823
[2,] 0.645632 0.563647
R>
```

Code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat hh(int n, int m) {
  arma::mat Z = arma::mat(n,m,arma::fill::randu);
  return Z;
}

/*** R
hh(2, 2)
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! As a beginner, I sincerely appreciate your help! I have also benefited a lot from your blog and some online examples. In fact, my question posted here is just a simplified version of original question. The original one is that if the argument passed on to function is null (argument may be matrix, scalar, vector, character string), I will initialize them in the function. I have tried many approaches, always got an error "static assertion failed error: type mismatch or unsupported type". Feel very upset and helpless!

Comment: Two answers: We have a generic and powerful way with `Rcpp::Nullable<>()`, see other answers here and at the Rcpp Gallery.  A `matrix()` does not come into Armadillo a size 0x0 (not sure if there is a constraint about it) but rather 1x1 with element being `NA`. You _can_ test for that. Also, easiest way to see for a `arma::mat M;` is to invoke `M.print("matrix M");`.   Lastly please feel free to accept the answer (by clicking on the "tick" mark you as question asker see).